# How create one route with multi method in there?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I would like create one route with index method and all method name if exist can be call. Is any way to do this ?

```
Route::get('/{params}/table', TableController@index)->name(table.index)
```

Now in controller i would like create index method and all request should go there. I want get params as method and try call if exist.

```
public function index(Request $request) {
        dd($request);
    }
```

How can i do this ?

UPDATE

I think i need smth like:

```
Route::get('/{params}/abc/{any?}, function(any) {
    get params $any
    call function from TableController@any
});
```

and if method exist in TableController

Comment: Not very clear question, assuming you mean this `Route::any('/{params}/table', TableController@index)`?

Comment: i updated  post if u caould take a look

Comment: You could do `$request->all()` and `$request->query()` to get the request data. If you have route like this `'/{params}/abc/{any?}` it will be the first parameter in your controller index method.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple receive `$params` or `$any` variable in the controller

```
public function index($params, $any) {
    dd($any);
}
```

and than check if needed method exists.